# "Let $G$ be a finite group with a normal subgroup $N\cong S_3$. Show there is $H\le G$ s.t. $G=N\times H$." Does this $=$ really mean $\cong$?

Tags: group-theory, notation, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, direct-product

I'm attempting Problem 60 on [this problem set](https://www.math.kent.edu/%7Ewhite/qual/list/group.pdf).

> 60. Let $G$ be a finite group with a normal subgroup $N\cong S_3$. Show that there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $G = N \times H$.

I'm guessing the author meant to say "$G\cong N\times H$" instead of what he wrote? What do you think?

**Edit:** I just saw he repeats this notation in other exercises, like

> 61. A group $N$ is said to be complete if the center of $N$ is trivial and every automorphism of $N$ is inner. Show that if $G$ is a group, $N\lhd G$, and $N$ is complete, then $G = N \times C_G(N)$.

So maybe it's a lazy notation for $\cong$? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: yes, it should be an isomorphism instead of an equality

Comment: Here they are talking about the *internal* direct product, in which case you have equality. The internal direct product is isomorphic to the external direct product, which is likely what you are thinking about. In the end, though, the distinction turns out to be largely irrelevant.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How does the internal direct product differ from standard product of subgroups? Or is it a way to say that $NH=G$ and $N\cap H=\{1\}$?

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón add that both subgroups are normal and you've got it. It is different because it is not a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: Ok, then it's just an operator that gives you extra info, like the $\oplus$ for direct sums or $\dot\cup$ for disjoint union?

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón: Yes, that's right. In this context, $G=N\times H$ means that (i) $G$ equals $NH$, and (ii) that $N$ and $H$ and normal subgroups of $G$ with trivial intersection. This is indeed similar to how, if we write $W=U\oplus V$ in the context of vector spaces, then it combines an operation – $W=U+V$ – and an assertion – "$U$ and $W$ have trivial intersection". That being said, I think it is quite common to reserve the symbol $\times$ for the *external* direct product, and simply use prose to say that $G$ is the internal direct product of two subgroups.

Comment: Personally, I am not fond of using symbols for internal products/sums, etc. I think notation that combines assertions and operations can give off the wrong impression. Notice that if we insist that $\times$ denotes the internal direct product, then $N\times H$ is meaningless unless we specify which group $N$ and $H$ are considered to be subgroups of; however, the notation makes it look like $N\times H$ has some kind of independent meaning.

Comment: @Joe But $N \times H$ is correct in this context because $N$ and $H$ are specific subgroups. The required conclusion $G = N \times H$ is stronger than $G \cong N \times H$, so you need some way of distinguishing between them.

Comment: Why not $\otimes$?

Comment: @DerekHolt: I agree that we need some way of distinguishing between the two cases, but I would prefer to indicate the internal direct product with prose, rather than with any particular symbols.

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón At least for abelian groups $\otimes$ denotes a tensor product, which has a different meaning. You could use $\times_{\rm int}$ and $\times_{\rm ext}$, but which one is intended is usually clear from the context (which is the case in this question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, if $N$ and $H$ are two subgroups of a group $G$, then to say $G=N\times H$ means, by definition, that $N$ and $H$ are both normal, $N\cap H=\{1\}$, and $NH=G$.

The distinction between such an internal direct product and just an abstract isomorphism can be important. Consider the following example. Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and let $H=\langle (2,0)\rangle$. This is a subgroup of order $2$, and it is true that $G$ is abstractly isomorphic to a direct product of a group of order $2$ and some other group. But there is no $N\leq G$ such that $G=N\times H$. We say that $H$ has no complement in $G$, which is a property that one is often interested in.

Comment: "$G$ is abstractly isomorphic to a group of order 2
 and some other group." Do you mean here that "$G$ is abstractly isomorphic to *the external direct product of* a group of order 2 and some other group."?

Comment: Thanks, @LucaT.Castrillón, corrected.